# How do you bind a grid's children to a list?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, grid, bind

In my ViewModel I have a list of items that I would like a grid in my view to bind to (the items will be the grids children). The list is a list of view models for the items.

How do you bind a grid to the list (I can access .children in code but not xaml)? 
Also, how do you specify the data template (another xaml file) for the view models in the list so that they are rendered correctly within the grid.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use an `ItemsControl` with the `ItemsPanel` set to a Grid :

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TheList}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Grid/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

In the `ItemsControl`'s `ItemContainerStyle`, you might want to bind the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` attached properties to some property of the items :

```
  <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding RowIndex}"/>
        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}"/>
    </Style>
  </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks. I also figured out the second part of my question if anyone else comes across this

<s:SurfaceUserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ProductDetailsViewModel}">
            <v:ProductDetails />
        </DataTemplate>   
    </s:SurfaceUserControl.Resources>

Comment: This is works a treat if you know how many rows and columns you need, but what if you want as many as the maximum row/column? Is there a way to autogenerate the row/column definitions?