# WPF: Binding items added to UserControl's exposed children

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls, children

I have a user control that allows items to be added to it by exposing a Grid's Children property. Any control I add shows up fine but when I try to bind a property on the added item to a control in the main window nothing happens (example):

```
<TextBox Name="txtTest" Text="Success!" />

<mycontrols:CustomUserControl.ExposedGridChildren>
     <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=txtTest, Path=Text, FallbackValue=fail}"/>
</mycontrols:CustomUserControl.ExposedGridChildren>
```

This example always results in the TextBox's text showing "fail". Here is how I'm exposing the children in the user control:

```
public UIElementCollection ExposedGridChildren
    {
        get { return grdContainer.Children; }
    }
```

Any thoughts? Is it a scope issue? I know I can't name the elements I add to the children because of scope errors. Thanks, Brian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was apparently going about this thing all wrong. What I needed to do was create a look-less control and template it to have one (or more) contentpresenter(s).

Answer (score 0):

This might answer your question: 
[How do you bind a grid's children to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395701/how-do-you-bind-a-grids-children-to-a-list)

Or as Dr. WPF puts it: (http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/10/15/itemscontrol-a-is-for-abundance/)

> Is a Panel an ItemsControl?
>
> No. The logical children of a panel
>   are UIElements, whereas the logical
>   children of an ItemsControl (its
>   Items) can be any CLR objects.
>
> Sidebar: So what is a panel? The main
>   role of a panel is to provide layout
>   support for its children. Although a
>   panel does maintain a collection of
>   child elements, it is not technically
>   a WPF “control”… That is, it does not
>   derive from the Control base class and
>   it does not support the WPF notion of
>   templating. Instead, it is a single
>   element with a single purpose… namely,
>   to size and position (a.k.a., measure
>   and arrange) its children.

Comment: An itemscontrol seems to function exactly the same way. Perhaps I'm exposing it incorrectly? Now it's:

     public ItemCollection ExposedItemsControlItems{
            get { return grdContainer.Items; }
        }

I can still add controls and they show fine in the host window but I still can't bind outside the usercontrol.

On a side note: I'm not binding a collection to the usercontrol I'm actually putting them into the xaml directly. Since I will be using this usercontrol over many forms I need the ability to add different controls to it on each form.