# WPF Binding Grid Children UIElementCollection

Tags: wpf, binding, grid, children

I have a list of Rectangle shapes which I keep in memory,

I want to bind this list of rectangles to a Grid so that the Grid will display the rectangles as its children.

So when I update this list of rectangles (adding, removing) it would be updated in the display.
I know I can do this programatically by accessing the children property of the Grid and adding and removing the rectangles but  for difficult reasons to explain I want to use the Binding feature....

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use an itemscontrol in this case, since binding directly to the Children property of a panel is not possible. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889825/wpf-is-it-possible-to-bind-a-canvass-children-property-in-xaml) for the same situation, except that it's using a canvas.

Comment: [A more detailed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395701/how-do-you-bind-a-grids-children-to-a-list) explaining how one might use the `ItemsControl` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Put the Rectangles in an ObservableCollection.