# How to dynamically add grids into grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, grid

For my current projet i want to make an UI where information are displayed on "tile" which i designed as a Grid with other Label and progress bar into. But i can't figure out how to make those tiles displayed on my main grid.

I already tried Gridview that didn't work with the exemples on the web and making someway without grid isn't really easy.

This is the grid to insert as many times as needed

```xml
<Grid Margin="10" Background="AntiqueWhite" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Label Content="{Binding fieldname}" FontFamily="Arial Black" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding datebegin}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="85,85,0,0" FontFamily="Arial Black" FontSize="18" />
            <Label Content="{Binding dateend}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="285,85,0,0" FontFamily="Arial Black" FontSize="18" />
             <ProgressBar Margin="0,150,0,0" Value="{Binding progression}" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50" />
            </Grid>
```

I need a way to add the exact tile produced into a grid (or anything else that can get onto a scrollviewer with 3 column and unlimited lines obviously).

Comment: A `Grid` has a `Children` property to which you can add any `UIElement`.

Comment: Not sure if are asking about `UserControl`, where you can group various controls and then reuse it multiple times. Consider to check [mvvm approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1396868/1997232) for more abstract visualization of e.g. `List<MyItem>` into table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the xmal. I have used ItemsControl and the WrapPanel as ItemsPanelTemplate to wrap the ItemsControl's items

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Add" Height="26" Width="75" Command="{Binding Add}" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <ScrollViewer Height="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Margin="10,10,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                        <StackPanel Width="200" Height="Auto">
                            <Label Content="{Binding fieldname}" FontFamily="Arial Black" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                            <Label Content="{Binding datebegin}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontFamily="Arial Black" FontSize="18" />
                            <Label Content="{Binding dateend}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontFamily="Arial Black" FontSize="18" />
                            <ProgressBar Value="{Binding progression}" Margin="5,10,5,10" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And the viewmodel is

```
public class Item
{
    public string fieldname
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string datebegin
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string dateend
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string progression
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Item(int number)
    {
        fieldname = "Filed name " + number;
        datebegin = "12-12-12";
        dateend = "14-12-12";
        progression = (5 * number).ToString();
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ICollection<Item> Items
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    }

    public ICommand Add
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand((a) =>
            {
                Items.Add(new Item(Items.Count));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Relaycommand

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;
    private Predicate<object> canExecute;
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return canExecute == null || canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {

        execute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't there a solution which is less complicated because i need this system for like 3 different stuff so it seems a little heavy code

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your requirement, what do you mean by 3 stuff, is it 3 different data types?

Comment: You can ignore the relay command,I just posted it as full example suppose if you want use the code I provided for debugging

Comment: Actually i have a kind of data like movies to list this way but also other datas like cars, obviously i'll not use the same template but the same conception

Comment: In that case you can define different data templates and based on your data type you bind the data template

Comment: Thanks so much and in the case I use a materialDesign card is it the same ? Sorry for the many question but i keep discovering the language for this project